# What’s the difference between “by its” and “for its”?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I can't see the difference in meaning in the phrase below. Both are correct?

> Cambridge is famous **by its** university.
>
> Cambridge is famous **for its** university.

I found this phrase in a book named 'Essential Grammar in Use' Second edition (Murphy, Raymond) In this book the autor used **'for'** in this context.

But there's a lot of references in internet using 'by' and it confuse me a lot.

There's an example using **"by"**

"Cambridge may be said to be sufficiently famous by its University"

Pigot and co.'s pocket atlas, topography and gazetteer of England
by James Pigot  (page 54)

https://books.google.com.br/books?id=RwgHAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA54&dq=cambridge+is+famous++%22by+its+university%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiguNL184HLAhWCGpAKHejvAZIQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=cambridge%20is%20famous%20%20%22by%20its%20university%22&f=false

Could you guys help me to solve this doubt, please?

Comment: The difference is that the second is grammatical while the first isn't. You can make the first grammatical by replacing "is famous" with "is *made* famous".

Comment: @Lawrence thank you! I updated the topic with another example I found in a book. "Cambridge may be said to be sufficiently famous by its University" It's the same case?

Comment: I have an idea about how *by* may be grammatical in the second example, but can't post an answer because your question was put on hold. You'll need to do some work first. To try to take the question off hold, I suggest you check standard references for the word "by", think about them, then edit your question to post your thoughts + links to the references you found. After that, you can go to the [meta site](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/) to ask for your question to be reopened. [This blog post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/12/you-could-look-it-up/) may also be helpful.

Comment: ... [Here's an example](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7516/reopen-request-what-is-the-origin-of-ex) of a request to reopen a question.

Answer (score 1):

In the narrow case of the example provided, only **for its** is appropriate.

**By** as a preposition means "beside," "near," or "through the agency of."  See [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by).

**For** in this instance is a preposition meaning "because of" or "with respect to".  Again, see [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for)

Comment: thank you! I updated the topic with another example I found in a book. "Cambridge may be said to be sufficiently famous by its University" It's the same case?